# Symfony2 .htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, amazon-ec2

I have a Symfony2 app deployed on EC2 instance in amazon.

I try to rewrite a.htaccess to modify the address:

http://ec2-xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/symfony/web/app.php/mysite

The problem is modify /symfony/web/app.php to show just /mysite

What i need to modify in the .htaccess?

Thanks

Comment: Would be helpful if you show your `.htaccess` file and tell what is set as `DocumentRoot` in `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `VirtualHost` setup has correct `DocumentRoot`. It should point to `web` directory like this - `/var/www/symfony/web`

Comment: yes, i do this but the problem is doesn't show app.php..any idea?

Comment: `.htaccess` file has to have this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]` in order to forward every request to `app.php`

Comment: you mean the .htaccess in the symfony directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Maybe you could a little explanation.